# Split record with start- and enddate into separate records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to split record with start- and enddate into separate records in SQL?

Example:

```
Start Date      End Date
05/09/2000      12/31/2002
```

---

The result should be:

```
Start Date      End Date
05/09/2000      12/31/2000
01/01/2001      12/31/2001
01/01/2002      12/31/2002
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE.  In SQL Server, this would look like:

```
with cte as (
      select start_date, end_date
      from t
      union all
      select datefromparts(year(start_date) + 1, 1, 1), end_date
      from cte
      where datediff(year, start_date, end_date) > 0
     )
select start_date,
       (case when datediff(year, start_date, end_date) > 0
             then datefromparts(year(start_date), 12, 31)
             else end_date
        end)
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27cee879df6738c889f7a6fd084904f7) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Start Date] date,[End Date] date)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('05/09/2000','12/31/2002')

 Select B.*
  From  @YourTable A
  Cross Apply (
                Select [Start Date] = min(D)
                      ,[End Date]   = max(D)
                 From ( Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[Start Date],[End Date])+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[Start Date]) 
                         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                      ) B1
                 Group By Year(D)
              ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Start Date  End Date
2000-05-09  2000-12-31
2001-01-01  2001-12-31
2002-01-01  2002-12-31
```

Comment: can i got explain about top query

Comment: @learner The declare YourTable is just a demonstrative table variable.  The CROSS APPLY does all the work.   It creates a list of dates between Start Date and End Date and then performs a min/max grouped by year.

Comment: thank you  sir much more 
i understand above statement but i didn't get this master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
what is that and what is mean function they are do?

Comment: @learner just a table that is known to be available.  Any table of appropriate size will do,  This is used to create an ad-hoc tally (or numbers) table.